# How do I know if my laptop can take an NVMe SSD upgrade?

Tags: ssd, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon 5th Gen 20HR.  I'd like to upgrade the SSD.  How do I know if it can take an NVMe SSD? I've tried to find the specs online but can't find any reference to what kind of drive it has.

Comment: You can check if you open Device Manager or msinfo32 and view Storage Information.

Comment: That's only a guess, but downvote was probably because this asked like too personal question which helps only for specific configuration, while this site is supposed to be about slightly more general cases and general solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a page that seems to be the one of your laptop:
[link to page](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-x1/ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-5th-Gen/p/22TP2TXX15G)

It mentions a PCIE SSD, that should mean that your laptop supports NVME, but if you are still in doubt the best way know is oppening up the machine and looking at the ssd **slot**.
[m.2 ssd types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/595eT.jpg) If looks like its supposed to fit the one on the top of the image, you're good. Remember that the shape of the ssd itself doesn't matter, pay attention to witch of the ssds on the image the **slot** is supposed to fit because there's a chance that NVME is supported but your laptop was shipped with an m.2 SATA drive,

Answer (score 1):

> How do I know if it can take an NVMe SSD

According to the specifications for your device it appears that your device already has a NVMe SSD installed.

> [image]

Specifications: [ThinkPad X1 Carbon (5th Gen)](https://psref.lenovo.com/Detail/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_X1_Carbon_5th_Gen?M=20HR006JUS)

There realistically isn’t any limitations on the storage size of the NVMe device your supports.  It appears the maximum size in 2017 supported was 512 GB.

Answer (score 1):

That machine will take an NVMe drive.  I have a ThinkPad X1 4th
20FB here with a 1 TB PICe NVMe SSD drive.

It works great and is very fast.